# Missing ftw.h support in android ndk?

Tags: android-ndk

i'm trying to build gcc-4.9 with android ndk to cross-compile it to run on android.
i've found ftw.h in platform-21 includes:

```
MBA-Anton:cctools-native asmirnov$ find /softdev/android-ndk-r10c -name "ftw.h"
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-mips/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-mips64/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/include/ftw.h
/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/include/ftw.h
```

I'm trying to get standalone toolchain:

```
${NDKDIR}/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --arch=x86 --install-dir=./tmp/x86-android --toolchain=x86-4.9
```

But i can't see ftw.h in include folder:

```
MBA-Anton:cctools-native asmirnov$ find ./tmp -name "ftw.h"
MBA-Anton:cctools-native asmirnov$
MBA-Anton:cctools-native asmirnov$ ls ./tmp/x86-android
COPYING         bin         lib         sysroot
COPYING.LIB     i686-linux-android  libexec
SOURCES         include         share
```

when i'm trying to build the tool with that standalone toolchain after it's configured with

```
--with-sysroot=/softdev/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-x86
```

ftw.h can't be found and i'm getting compile error